# Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'LoadFromDataTable'

Tags: powershell

When I run the script below, I receive the error "Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'LoadFromDataTable'".  Not sure how to fix this problem.

The script reads csv file and exports to excel file.  Must keep the leading zeros in column #9.

cmdlet ConvertCSVToXLS6.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputFile: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\powershell_scripts\inputfile.csv
OutputFile: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\powershell_scripts\test.xls
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'LoadFromDataTable'.
At C:\Users\xxx\Documents\powershell_scripts\ConvertCSVToXLS6.ps1:20 char:1

- $range = $worksheet.Range("A1").LoadFromDataTable($data, $true)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (LoadFromDataTable:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
  ```

-----------------------script--------------------------------

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$InputFile,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$OutputFile
)

# Load the CSV data
$data = Import-Csv $InputFile

# Create a new Excel workbook
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

# Get the first worksheet
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

# Write the CSV data to the worksheet
$range = $worksheet.Range("A1").LoadFromDataTable($data, $true)

# Format column 9 to retain leading zeros
$range = $worksheet.Range("I:I")
$range.NumberFormat = "000000000"

# Save the workbook as XLS format
$workbook.SaveAs($OutputFile, -4143)

# Close the workbook and quit Excel
$workbook.Close()
$excel.Quit()`
```

Not sure how to find/fix the missing method 'LoadFromDataTable'.

Comment: Seems `LoadFromDataTable` is an extension from EPPlus. See also: https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/LoadFromDataTable and https://www.epplussoftware.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are following a tutorial where 3rd-party stuff is used, as the range object doesn't have a method called LoadFromDataTable netiher in [VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)#methods) nor in [.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range?view=excel-pia#methods), and using the search box there are 0 results for this name in the entire documentation. Always refer to the docs in these cases by the way, however I can not find a COM-specific object model, so one can only guess that it is the VBA one...
But you don't need to load the csv, prepare a new workbook, and paste: Excel can open csv. Just open it and save. And format before save if necessary.